# Loading Html File into iOS app

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

when i load local html file into my iOS app every thing work fine but in the html file there is an animation (images+sounds) the sounds file founded under the folder reference "edge in folder named media " the problem is the animated images work fine but without any sound can any one advice me ?

and there is my code

```
    localContent = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 1024, 768)];
           NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"inDirectory:@"Edge"];

            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            [localContent loadRequest:request];

            [self.view addSubview: localContent];
```

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/8044447/1403732 and also post part of your html related to sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;

MyWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some java script code when your webview finish loading delegate is called..

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSURLRequest* request = [webView request];
    NSString *page = [request.URL lastPathComponent];
    if ([page isEqualToString:@"index.html"]){
        NSString *js = @"startVideo();";
        [myWebMain stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    }
}
And here's my javascript function:

<script>
function startVideo(){
var pElement3 = document.getElementById('myVideo');
pElement3.play();
}
</script>
And here's the html in case you're new to html video

<video id="myVideo" poster="index_poster.png" width="1024" height="768" xcontrols     autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="flow.m4v" type="video/mp4"/>
browser not supports the video
</video>
```

Comment: how to add this script to my code also when load html not invoke web view finish load

Comment: can you please show me you html code which you are using form local?

Comment: how to insert java script